# Ansible: `RequirementParseError` when feeding a variable to `pip: name=pkg version="{{ v }}"`

Tags: ansible

When I have this role:

```
# playbooks/roles/ansible/tasks/main.yml
- name: Install Ansible
  pip:
    state: present
    name: ansible
    version: "{{ ansible_version }}"

# playbooks/roles/ansible/defaults/main.yml
ansible_version: 1.9.4
```

I get this error while running `ansible-playbook` version 1.9.4 or 2.0.0.2:

```
TASK: [ansible | Install Ansible] *********************************************
failed: [localhost] => {"cmd": "/usr/local/bin/pip install ansible=={'major': 1, 'full': '1.9.4', 'string': '1.9.4\\n  configured module search path = None', 'minor': 9, 'revision': 4}", "failed": true}
msg:
:stderr: Invalid requirement: 'ansible=={major:'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 73, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3036, in parse
    req, = parse_requirements(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2980, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2945, in scan_list
    raise RequirementParseError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
RequirementParseError: Expected version spec in ansible=={major: at =={major:
```

This is the playbook:

```
- name: Install Sensu
  serial: "100%"
  hosts: all
  sudo: yes

  roles:
    - role: "ansible-pull"
      server_type: "sensu"
      ansible_version: "2"
```

Where the `ansible-pull` role depends on the `ansible` role in `meta/main.yml`.

Am I injecting the variable incorrectly in this case? Is there some problem with setting the variable in the dependent `ansible-pull` roll rather than directly in the `ansible` role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `ansible_version` is a magic variable set by Ansible.

Who knew?

Using an arbitrarily different but unused variable name does the trick.